# why does odp.net2 work for .net framework 4 and 2.0

Tags: .net, oracle, .net-4.0, odp.net

I have to deploy a web application with .net framework 4 on a windows server with oracle odp.net2 installed.

Reading the documentation the .net framework 4 should only work with odp.net4, but I successfully deploy the application in the server without odp.net4.

I wonder if I can use both odp.net2 or op.net4 on top of .net framework 4 with the same result.

I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Did you provide (by accident) a copy of file `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` Version 4.x with your installation? Check with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) what is loaded in reality. Did you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver? This one works in any case, even without any Oracle Client installation.

Comment: I did what you suggest, the result in the picture http://imgur.com/gATEhqE. I am not using odp.net managed driver because I need to connect to oracle 9 server.

Comment: Is this picture a joke? Filter on `Path Contains Oracle.DataAccess`